# Eclipse View Open location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a view that can be opened multiple times containing different data. I added a placeholder for the view in a folder that is below the editor area. The first instance of the view opens in the proper location but if I open a second version of the view it opens to the right of the editor. Is there a way to have all views of this type open in the folder below the editor like the first one does? Do I have to add multiple place holders? Even when I close the first instance of the view and open another instance of it, the new view opens to the right of the editor.

The views differ by the secondary id that populates the view based on that id.